# Specifying URL on EE

Tags: url, ee3

Let's say I'm making a site in EE and I want to specify a URL on a specific page. As a former wordpress dev, I did that with ease, how would I do that with EE?

Answer (score 0):

The slug used for every entry can be edited on the [URL title field](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/publish/create.html#url-title).

If you want to customize the full URL, you can use the [pages module](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/pages/index.html). It will make the [Pages Tab](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/publish/create.html#pages-tab) available, where you can type the full URL. Use it with parsimony.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Template Routes system.  This gives you extraordinary control over what templates are used to generate content in response to URL entries. Hugely powerful, but with quite a steep learning curve. If you are happy to buy an add on there is also Structure which overlays a Wordpress like environment over EE.